# Doctrine - General error: 1395 Can not delete from join view

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am getting this error when I try to remove an entity in Doctrine.

> General error: 1395 Can not delete from join view

My table structure is:

```
   user
   ----
   aid 
   name
   email
   ...

   role
   -----
    rid
    name

   users_roles
   -----------
    uid - foreign key references User.aid
    rid - foreign key, references Role.rid
```

The User-Role tables have a many-to-many relationship, with the users_roles as the mapping table . However, the developers who coded earlier chose to insert the rid in users_roles as comma separated role ids, instead of using different row for each (uid, rid) pair.

So, to define the associations in Doctrine properly, I created a view UsersRolesView as follows:

```
CREATE view `users_roles_view` AS SELECT `r`.`rid` AS `rid`, `ur`.`uid` AS `uid` 
FROM (`users_roles` `ur` JOIN `role` `r`)
WHERE (find_in_set(`r`.`rid`, `ur`.`rid`) > 0)
```

My doctrine mapping xml for the User entity looks like this:

I get the Doctrine error when I try to remove a user entity. The delete User function is given below:

```
function removeUser($aid)
{
   $admin = $GLOBALS['em']->find('Admin', $aid);
   $GLOBALS['em']->remove($admin);

   $GLOBALS['em']->flush();
}
```

Complete exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1395 Can not delete from join view 'users_roles_view'' in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php on line 754

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure this think exist in Doctrine2?

```
find_in_set()
```

Comment: The view was defined from MySQL, not via Doctrine. Doctrine just reads the view as an entity.